# Formatting a number

Tags: c#, strings, formatting

I'm writing out two numbers separated with a dash. The first number is padded with leading zeros until 6 digits, the second number, 4.

```
string taskNumber = order.ID.ToString("D6") + "-" + task.ID.ToString("D4");
```

If I was going to rewrite this using string.Format I would simply say:

```
string taskNumber = string.Format("{0}-{1}", order.ID.ToString("D6"), task.ID.ToString("D4"));
```

Is there anything I can do with `string.Format`'s `{0}` and `{1}` to say that I want my numbers padded? Calling `ToString` is a bit verbose, IMO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure. Simply include the padding specifier directly in the format string:

```
string taskNumber = string.Format("{0:D6}-{1:D4}", order.ID, task.ID);
```